# How to set up conversion tracking in Google Ads?

Tags: ads, google-adsense, google-ads

Google says I need to set up conversion tracking for my ads.  I followed the instructions.  I got my google tag and pasted it into my site.  I clicked their test button and confirmed it's working.  Next, I chose my conversion page. I want "Sales" for my conversion, so I chose my Thank You page.  Makes sense, right?  When someone lands on the thank you page, a sale has been made and it should show a conversion.  But that's where the instructions end.  I did watch their video and it mentioned my conversion page needs a "Snippet" pasted into it.  There's no indication where to get this "Snippet" though. You would think they would give it to you at the time you selected your conversion page.  I guess that would be too easy.  If this is my problem, where can I get the snippet?   Thank you.